# How to reset password using Microsoft Graph Client SDK(C#)?

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

How can a user reset his password using Microsoft Graph client.
I am not able to find the right way to do it. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Tom is correct about this the Delegate Scope `Directory.AccessAsUser.All` allowing the signed-in user to change their password. The standard `User.ReadWrite` can update most properties, but it *cannot* update the user's password.

It is, however, a supported operation. The SDK includes the `PasswordProfile` class you need to pass into Graph. The syntax would look something like this:

```
await graphClient.Me.Request().UpdateAsync(new User() {
    PasswordProfile = new PasswordProfile() {
        Password = "newPassword",
        ForceChangePasswordNextSignIn = true
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

> How can a user reset his password using Microsoft Graph client

**Unfortuntly**, it seems that we can't reset password with Microsoft Graph client currently. According to the Microsoft graph [update user API](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_update), we required to use the delegated [permission type](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/permissions_reference): `Directory.AccessAsUser.All`.

> When updating the passwordProfile property, the following permission is required: **Directory.AccessAsUser.All.**
>
> **Delegated permissions** are used by apps that have a signed-in user present. For these apps either the user or an administrator consents to the permissions that the app requests and the app is delegated permission to act as the signed-in user when making calls to Microsoft Graph.