# Open navigation properties are not supported on OpenTypes. Property name: 'DirectoryDataService.changePassword'

Tags: azure, active-directory

Error shown When i try to update user password using Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient

```
  user.ChangePasswordAsync(currentPassword, newPassword);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works correctly for me with following code.

```
await activeDirectoryClient.Users["userObjectId"].ChangePasswordAsync("oldPassword", "newPassword");
```

or

```
 var user = activeDirectoryClient.Users.GetByObjectId("userObjectId")
 await user.ChangePasswordAsync("oldPassword", "newPassword");
```

But I can this **reproduce** the error information with following code.

```
 var user =(User)activeDirectoryClient.Users.GetByObjectId("userObjectId").ExecuteAsync().Result;
 await user.ChangePasswordAsync("oldPassword", "newPassword");
```

I capture the request with fiddler then I find that 400 error. And the request url is

```
https://graph.windows.net/{tenantId}/directoryObjects/{userId}/changePassword?api-version=1.6
```

But the change password Graph API is

```
https://graph.windows.net/{tenantId}/users/<objectId>/changePassword or /users/userPrincipalName/changePassword
```

I assume that it is the reason why get that error information.

[image]

**Note:** Call the changePassword action for the **signed-in user** to change their own password.

We also could use the Microsoft graph SDK to do that. For more information, please refer to another [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50286384/how-to-reset-password-using-microsoft-graph-client-sdkc).

Comment: Thanks this code working fine:                                                                                           var user = activeDirectoryClient.Users.GetByObjectId("userObjectId")
 await user.ChangePasswordAsync("oldPassword", "newPassword");                                          I am getting below error : System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceClientException: {"odata.error":{"code":"Authorization_RequestDenied","message":{"lang":"en","value":"Access to change password operation is denied."}}}

Comment: The Application has Company Administrator Permissions

Comment: @AmerJamaeen As I mentioned that changePassword action for the **signed-in** user to change their **own** password.  It means that it can be changed only  by themselves who signed-in. So you got the change password operation is denied. You also could get that information from this [document](https://msdn.microsoft.com/Library/Azure/Ad/Graph/api/functions-and-actions#changePassword).

Comment: If target user isn't the signed-in user , it will throw error :Access to change password operation is denied.